# JavaScript ajax post command error for localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to Ajax & JavaScript. But i am stuck with this error. I am making post request using Ajax.

```
var sentdata = {"name":"gourav", "email":"email"};
var sentd = JSON.stringify(sentdata);
this.url = "http://localhost/Working/board.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).url,
    data: sentd,
    contentType: "application/json",
    //dataType : "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.message);
        console.log( "Done with success: ");
    },
    error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

I am calling this request to simple code where i am not even checking the `$_POST` variable and just trying to write some data in mysql table.

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, true);
// selecting database
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $con);
if(1)
{
    $tb_name = "tb_appuser";
    $name = "name1";
    $email="email1";
    $deviceId="0";
    $platform="1";
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (user_name, email, device_regid, platform_type) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d')" , $tb_name, $name, $email, $deviceId, $platform);
    echo "$query\n";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}
```

I already tested this board.php code and verified it is inserting the data in table.

But when i am doing this via $ajax i am getting "The page at localhost says: undefined" and nothing got written in my database also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url: this.url`, not `$(this).url`.
`$(this)` does not have a property called "url" in your context I think.

Comment: I was able to send the command after removing $. Now even i am able to call restapi calls also on my localhost.